# Source: quote about problem solving

Tags: quote

I have an approximation of a quote lodged in my brain, and I'm looking to source it:

> Whenever you don't understand something, there is a simpler thing that you also don't understand.

I am almost certain this quote was due to a mathematician or physicist, but I can't track it down.  Does it ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: Sounds like a famous thing Pólya [may or may not have said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086285/did-pólya-say-can-or-cannot).

Comment: Am I correct in that the above quote implies that either the set of "things" has no well-ordered subsequence or that there is not even a single thing that can be understood? And if so, does that mean that the quote was intended to be ironic?

Comment: @yoniLavi I use it often, under the form “If you can't solve a problem, then there is an easier problem you can't solve: find it.”, without any irony.

Comment: This seems to be a well-known principle among teachers. An instance of awareness of a lack of understanding is almost always preceded by an instance of *unconscious* non-understanding.

Comment: Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos, and sorry to be so literally minded, but with your phrasing I also still hit the same paradox of infinite regress. As I see it, at some point in the process, even though there might be an even easier problem, the student has to decide to put their mind into addressing *this* problem, otherwise they would never get anywhere. So maybe, to (poorly) paraphrase your sentence, “If you can't solve a problem, then there is an easier related problem you *can* solve: find it, and then build on it to solve the original.”

Answer (score 1):

Accordin to [THIS](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gmelvin/polya.pdf), Pólya included "Solve a simpler problem" as one strategy in his book *How to Solve It*.